# How to open a file with a different program command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

My **test.ps1** is opening with **notepad** but I want it to open with **powershell.exe** .  Is there any way I can make it open with **powershell**  through **command prompt ONLY**

EDIT:

Thanks to harrymc he figured a way out!

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command" /ve /d "\"C:\Window\System32\Windows\PwerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe\" \"%1\"" /f
```

Comment: I would caution the association of .ps1 with PowerShell.exe instead of PowerShell IDE.  Running `powershell.exe filename` should run the script, the way to determine if there is a problem with the script, is to run the script within a PowerShell prompt and provide the results as a screenshot.

Comment: Try without 'start'.  See syntax here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436405/how-to-run-powershell-in-cmd#16436712

Comment: @cliff2310 New-Item C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\Test.txt

Comment: What security error you don't want to turn off? Please add to question. If you mean powershell execution policy you can add the switch '-executionpolicy bypass' . See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63532269/2953889

Comment: @lx07 I dont want trojans running powershell commands on my computer is there any other way?

Comment: The '-executionpolicy' switch only applies to that command, you don't need to change system security setting if you don't want to. Please do try and update your question with your errors/conserns as it's not that clear at the moment...

Comment: your comment is great but how to do that in command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Associate .PS1 to Open in PowerShell**

- Right-click any `.ps1` file in Explorer, and select "Open with..."
- If PowerShell isn’t listed, click on "More apps"
- Place a check-mark in "Always use this app to open .ps1 files"
- Click on "Look for another app on this PC"
- Position to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`
- Select `powershell.exe`
- Click Open.

**Method 2: Change Default Program via the registry**

- Run `regedit`
- Copy the following into the address bar and press Enter:
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command`
- Double-click the `(Default)` value on the right
- Copy the following into "Value data" and click OK:
  `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "%1"`
- Close the Registry Editor.

To do all this in one
[reg add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add) 
command, do:

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command" /ve /d "\"C:\Window\System32\Windows\PwerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe\" \"%1\"" /f
```

Note that the argument `/ve` refers to the `(Default)` item.
The double-quotes in the value also need to be escaped with `\`.

Comment: if I change the value data to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe will it still work?

Comment: It should work. If you're worried, export the `Command` key as backup.

Comment: do you have any idea how can I do it thru command prompt btw?

Comment: I've tried this but didnt work `reg delete HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command /v UpgradeDone

reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command /v UpgradeDone /t Reg_Sz /d "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "%1" `

Comment: I added the command to my answer. You just need to replace the value, so no need for a delete.

Comment: Thanks! according to my search this also works `reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_SZ /d C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /f`

Comment: It should work, but I always prefer to play it safe.

Comment: I do it in virtual machine anyway!